# Only homepage loads slowly on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

On this site:  https://tokyopicnics.com/ (bilingual with woocommerce) 
only the homepage loads very slowly (10 seconds). The other pages are fine. I tried w3 total cache plugin but no difference. I asked my hosting company and they said it was a coding issue after I sent them the gtmetrix.com results. Any way to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Clawdius. There isn't enough information here for us to be able to provide you much help, or to be considered a good question. You have access to the site, the code and the hosting and cannot figure out the issue... we can't do it from this description

Comment: I've experienced the same as you – hard to find any answer to the phenomenon. People tend to focus on what is on the page, rather than the fact that exactly the same page loads a lot slower when it is set as 'wordpress static front page' = home. Did you get any good explanation why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install the [Debug Bar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/). This is the easiest way to inspect what is taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if it might be a plugin that's causing the slow-down. Try disabling all the plugins and re-enable them one by one to see if one of them is causing the issue.

You can also use Chrome Dev Tools to profile what's causing the issue. Open dev tools and go to the 'Performance' tab. Then click the reload icon: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6xht2rmz95h710/Screenshot%202018-10-11%2013.11.44.png?dl=0

It will then reload the page and provide (very detailed) info on what's loading and how long it's taking to load and parse.

Comment: Thanks. New to Dev Tools so will check tutorials

Comment: see comments below

Answer (score 0):

Rather often that behavior happens when some plugin or your theme does external http request as a part of homepage rendering.
Install QueryMonitor https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ plugin and check if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks. PHP Errors (1 Deprecated) Function create_function() is deprecated Location: wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/essential-grid.php:98 I disabled that plugin but no change.

Answer (score 0):

It's the large images, and the number of images, in your home page slider that take a while to load compared to the other pages.

To really get a picture of the page loading times, (in chrome), open the developer tools, go to 'Performance' tab, and click on 'Start profiling and reload page'. That will give you a breakdown of all the load times.

Comment: Thanks. The hp Rev Slider has 2 images. I disabled it but it made no difference. Also disabled all plugins except Woocommerce & WPML (disabled Woocommerce before but Checked Dev Tools performance but can't understand results meaning exactly. According to gtmetrix.com the 2 main problems are Defer parsing of javascript and Remove query strings from static resources so tried "Speed Booster Pack" plugin with combinations of those 2 checked but only changed frontend appearance: full width to boxed, main menu removed.

Comment: Also added to functions.php
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
return "$url' defer ";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );

Comment: Everything in the developer tools event log, after folowing the procedure I mentions, seem to point to trx.addons.js. Seems to be firing some animation over and over which ends after `6 secs my side (bad ping). Try removing whater animations those are. I have no idea where trx.addons.js is coming from. a plugin though or the theme.

Comment: Thanks again. ThemeRex Addons is a plugin which I deactivated but no change. I'm using a Child-theme. I changed back to main theme and site loads normally so Child-theme seems to be the problem

Comment: Well glad you are starting to find the root cause. good luck with solving it.